Обработка кнопки на PHP
^C~/site $ php -S localhost:8080 index.php
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:20 2024] PHP 8.3.7 Development Server (http://localhost:8080) started
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:26 2024] 127.0.0.1:48484 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:26 2024] 127.0.0.1:48484 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:26 2024] 127.0.0.1:48488 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:26 2024] 127.0.0.1:48488 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:26 2024] 127.0.0.1:48492 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:26 2024] 127.0.0.1:48492 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:27 2024] 127.0.0.1:48496 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:27 2024] 127.0.0.1:48496 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:27 2024] 127.0.0.1:48500 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:27 2024] 127.0.0.1:48500 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:27 2024] 127.0.0.1:48504 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:27 2024] 127.0.0.1:48504 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:44 2024] 127.0.0.1:48508 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:44 2024] 127.0.0.1:48508 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:44 2024] 127.0.0.1:48512 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:44 2024] 127.0.0.1:48512 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:44 2024] 127.0.0.1:48516 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:44 2024] 127.0.0.1:48516 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:45 2024] 127.0.0.1:48520 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:45 2024] 127.0.0.1:48520 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:45 2024] 127.0.0.1:48524 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:45 2024] 127.0.0.1:48524 Closing
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:45 2024] 127.0.0.1:48528 Accepted
[Wed Jun 12 07:54:45 2024] 127.0.0.1:48528 Closing

index.php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Button Interaction Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="myButton" value="clicked">Click Me</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

php/start.php:
<?php
if(isset($_POST['start'])) {
  echo 123 . PHP_EOL;
}

Почему скрипт не выводит в консоль 123? Или онр выводиться в консоль браузера?

У вас какое-то нездоровое влечение к слову start. Попробуйте ответить себе на два вопроса: 1. Посмотрите на тег button в форме. Откуда в массиве $_POST должен появиться элемент с ключом start? 2. Посмотрите на атрибут action в форме. Какой файл будет запрошен браузером при отправке формы (и при чем здесь какое-то "php/start.php")?

И не очень понятно, какая "консоль" имеется в виду. Если обращаетесь к скрипту через браузер, то и весь вывод тоже будет в браузер. А если хотите выводить в консоль, то и выполнять скрипт надо как консольный, php index.php. Но никакие формы при этом, разумеется,  работать не будут.

action="process.php" - а где у вас файл process.php?

Кстати, при запуске веб-сервера index.php писать было не обязательно. Возможно, именно это сбило вас с толку. Сервер обслуживает все файлы в текущей директории, а не только один тот, который вы указали. Тем более что файл в этой команде служит совсем для другого
